# loop space homology and lens spaces

Tags: loop-spaces, homology, string-topology

Is the homology of free loop space of lens spaces known?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Coefficients in $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: There is paper by Loday "Free loop space and homology". It establishes isomorphism between cohomology of free loop space $LX$ and Hochschild homology of an algebra of singular cochains $S^*X$. Maybe this will help.

Comment: @Fernando Muro, Yes. But  \mathbb{Q} coefficeints is also fine.
@Sasha Patotski, thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: Do you mean for each component of the free loop space? The free loop space $LM$ has $p$ components for the lens space $M=L(p,q)$.